# Bootstrap footer: not aligned with the left side of the page. Rails template issue?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an odd problem with my "footer.html.erb" template it is 100% the size of the view but it's not flush with the left hand side so it makes the page about 10% wider than it would be it also looks ugly.

[image: Ugly footer]

I think the problem may be caused by the fact that the browser renders the closing div for `<div class="container">` after the footer divs. I don't know why.

This is my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ProfReview</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <!-- bootstrap stuff-->

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-block ">    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div,msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
      <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the footer.html.erb:

```
<div class="footer">
<footer class="footer">
  <p class="text-muted">Copyright 2016<p>
</footer>
  </div>
```

And lastly the footer.css

```
/* Footer */

footer {
  background-color: $footer;
  color: $white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Chrome renders this as:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-block ">        
<div class="panel panel-default">

 <!-- Main content -->

  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
<footer class="footer">
  <p class="text-muted">Copyright 2016 </p><p>
</p></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JSFiddle please

Comment: I believe this is a Rails template issue (perhaps), so I don't know how instructive a Fiddle would be but here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/tfantina/hfmnmo6p/

Comment: It's a mess. Seemingly ignoring the php code. If you can get a visual link that'd help us help you.

Comment: Oddly I just pushed it to Heroku and it does not seem to be a problem there.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using absolute positioning you can force `footer` to "attach" the ends by adding

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Because of those properties, you can leave out `width: 100%`.

You can also leave out `margin-top: 25px`, because absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document, so this margin won't affect other layout elements.

Your complete CSS declaration can then be

```
footer {
  background-color: $footer;
  color: $white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```